# iphone landscape mode problem again

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I have tested everything but I cant get it to work.

This is how I set up my program:

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: contentRect];
_view = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159/2);
_view.transform = transform;


_window.frame = contentRect;
_window.bounds = contentRect;
_window.window.bounds = contentRect;
_window.frame = contentRect;

_view.window.bounds = contentRect;
_view.bounds = contentRect;
_view.bounds = contentRect;
_view.frame = contentRect;

[_window addSubview: _view];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I set up my opengl like this:

```
glViewport(0, 0, 480, 320);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrthof( 0, 480, 0, 320, -1, 1 );

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

and as you can see one third from the right is black? what am i missing?
[image: iphone image]

Comment: Did the app start in portrait mode and then got rotated into landscape mode ?

Comment: yes, i dont know how to choose landscape mode from the beginning. i have put landscape mode in the .plist file but that does only rotate the phone, not its content

Comment: M_PI_2 is a convenient replacement for 3.14159/2

Answer (score 0):

You should set rotation in your  model/view matrix and not in the view.

Comment: when I set up the view port with glViewport(320, 480), and I only set _view.bounds = (480, 320) everything looks ok. But then I cant do glGetPixels later without twisting the image

Comment: because I guess glGetPixels get its size from the viewport, correct?

Comment: because if the viewport is 320*480, then i have to set this values in glGetPixels to get everything out, and then the image is 320*480 instead of 480*320 as i like to be

Comment: well, i don't see the problem. just rotate the resulting image.

Comment: well the rotation is correct, the height is 480 instead of 320 and vice verse. So if shrink it in y and make bigger in x, it will be the correct image, but how to do that?